# Angular 6 interceptor cannot handle response

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript, observable, interceptor

I have enabled on my Laravel API backend middleware from tymon `authorizeAndRefresh` which as I see it should get refresh the token and send back. For that purpose I've made an interceptor

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('fb_token');

    if (authToken) {
      const request = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken)
      });

      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        tap(event => {
          console.log(event);
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            if (event.headers['token']) {
              console.log(event.headers);
              const token = event.headers['Authorization'].split(' ')[1];
              localStorage.setItem('fb_token', token);
              this.store.dispatch({type: Actions.AUTHENTICATED});
            } else {
              this.store.dispatch({type: Actions.DEAUTHENTICATED});
            }
          }
        })
      );
    }

    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

However, it looks like there is no response handle since `console.log` is never invoked and further steps also.

Please help me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I added Notification Interceptor in [NGIR](https://github.com/mohammad-haji/ngir) project and it's working fine,
you can see an example of response interceptor in this file of project

[Link to NGIR Notification Interceptor](https://github.com/mohammad-haji/ngir/blob/master/src/app/config/interceptors/notification.interceptor.ts)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put a console.log right at the beginning of intercept() to see if it is triggered at all?

Have you added your interceptor class to your module providers as follow?

`import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';`

```
providers: [
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: MyHttpInterceptorClass,
  multi: true
}
```

Comment: Headers are added for outgoing requests

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple. Since I've got an authorization check on my server and also roles check I've been getting errors, however since interceptor is an `Osbervable` it has next callbacks `next, error, complete` and I handled only next, while getting error. Thus when I got errors I didn't get any headers.